# Nginx 404's aren't working - They just refresh the page

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-404

My 404 page https://epicmc.us/404.php loads perfectly fine if you type it in directly, but when you get a 404 error while browsing a page like https://epicmc.us/thispagedoesntexist (doesn't exist) it just kinda refreshes the page.. Almost like I'm typing in https://epicmc.us/#

This is my config.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   443;
    default_type text/html;  

    location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name epicmc.us;

    error_page 404 /usr/share/nginx/html/404.php;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.php;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: `error_page` last value is not filesystem path. It's URI to which nginx performs internal redirect.

Comment: So, `error_page 404 /404.php;` should work for you.